# obtain current logged in user

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Activedirectory as membership provider. I want to store the current logged in user in a session.

```
 protected void user_login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
 }
```

the code above gives the error below

---

```
The parameter 'username' must not be empty.
Parameter name: username 

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'username' must not be empty.
Parameter name: username
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: The parameter 'username' must not be empty.
Parameter name: username]
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckParameter(String& param, Boolean checkForNull, Boolean checkIfEmpty, Boolean checkForCommas, Int32 maxSize, String paramName) +1976411
   System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.CheckUserName(String& username, Int32 maxSize, String paramName) +30
   System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +86
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +82
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser() +19
   darts.login.user_login_LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Projects\DARTS\source\darts\darts\login.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnLoggedIn(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +179
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4211; ASP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Based upon using this from ASP.NET to get the login information about the currently authenticated user, I see a couple ways that this might work.  First, if you are using Forms authentication with the Active Directory membership provider, you could capture the username there.  Then you just put the username inside of the `GetUser()` method like so: `GetUser(yourUser)` and you should get the information needed.

If this isn't an option, I believe the username information is stored under your login control (in your case, I believe the name is `user_login` if you are indeed using a login control).  You would simply say `user_login.username` and put that inside the `GetUser()` method.

Finally, you could try the old fallback of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and put that inside of your `GetUser()` method.

Comment: Hi Biggs, Thanks for the answer. This gives currently logged in users of the windows. Im using active directory as membership provider. So the user tht logins into the website could be anyone from teh AD. I want to obtain this username that logs in

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash - Ahhh, I see.  Let me look into it and see what I can see.

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash - I updated my post to reflect my new understanding of your issue.  Since the old information wouldn't help, I decided to remove it.

Comment: Thanks Biggs. No luck with the getuser method. I used user_login.username. you are the man